# What is the best solution to visually showcase regional date comparisons

Tags: dates, interface, surveys, charts, reports

Currently, I have a bar graph that summarizes **3 regions** based on a specific date range (eg: Jan 03, 2012 - Jan 31, 2012)

Each region is based statistically by a couple of factors, the main one being its overall score (5 being the highest)

However, when a user compares the date range to a previous period or year (eg:Jan 03, 2012 - Jan 31, 2012 **compare to: Dec 03, 2011 - Dec 31, 2011**) I need to showcase a better way of presenting the overall score and percentage change of the 3 regions without making it too confusing. Its very similar to how Google Analytics compares its date ranges.

One solution I have is to keep the bar graph per region specific and let users tab through to see each region date comparison. This keeps the information organized and really easy to understand just in case a user has 3+ regions:

Jan 03, 2012 - Jan 31, 2012 
**Compare to: Dec 03, 2011 - Dec 31, 2011**

**[Region 1]** [Region 2] [Region 3]

{Region 1 Data Here}

Which charts are best when it comes to this type of information? What if the user wants to see all regions compared at once?

Here is the example i am talking about [Mockup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nr96bh7572ti9ia/region_view.jpg)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that every "region" shares the same set of data elements that comprise the bar chart? That is, the data could also be organized (using bastardized JSON): {elem1: {region1: val, region2: val, region3: val}, elem2: ...}. Is this an equally valid representation of the data? Also, is the number of regions fixed at three?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nr96bh7572ti9ia/region_view.jpg) to give you a better understanding. The regions can be as many as 5. With that being said, this could potentially be to many to fit for a overall summarized view. I'm starting to think a percentage change graph would be another solution

Comment: I see, so the regions *are* the data elements and are distinct from the date ranges? So flip my question then--is there also a fixed number of date ranges?

Comment: looking at the mockup, break it into 2 sections. The top where it shows the bar graph is actually being drawn up from only one specified date range (jan3-jan 31) and is not being compared to anything. The bottom section consists of info that is being compared by certain periods, for example: week, 30 days, 6 months, year. So going back to the question, what is the best way to showcase the bottom data (3 regions) in a way that compares the current date range (jan3-jan31) to its previous period (dec3-dec31) accordingly?

Comment: I'm curious what you think of my answer and whether you think I've understood your problem well enough.

Comment: Hi Ben, after thinking about your answer a bit more, I think this may actually work. Since my date ranges vary by week, month, 6 month and year, the grouping of the dates and how they compare can benefit the user no matter how many regions they would like to view at first. I think i was too focused on showing the overall date range as my x-axis statistic, which in turn, didn't really cover the main points i am trying to convey (overall score, regions, date range ) thanks for your help on this one!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your data correctly (and I'm not clear that I do), I recommend that you use a **grouped bar chart** as shown in this example:

[image]

In this example, we're comparing two different years, 2006 & 2007 by placing the corresponding sale counts for each region adjacent to each other. The benefit of a grouped bar chart in this case is that your users will be able to directly compare regions between date ranges (rather than indirectly comparing them by toggling an "active" date range).

It doesn't take much of a leap to see that if you require interactivity, you can make the legends (in this example: robbery, burglary, theft; in your example the date ranges) dynamic. That is, users can toggle certain date ranges on and off and have the bar chart update dynamically.